# Check if object of type X is in list and update corresponding field fails for reasons I don't understand

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to check if a list of Quests contains a Quest of Type `StartingQuest`. If it does, I want to increase the field OgresKilled that belongs to the Quest by 1.

The following code does not work.

I get the error message in the second line of code where I check ... == StartingQuest:

> Error CS0119  `StartingQuest` is a type, which is not valid in the
> given context

This does not make sense to me, as I explicitly want to check against the type.

```
if (Globals.ActiveQuests.Contains(new StartingQuest()))
{
    StartingQuest a = Globals.ActiveQuests.Find(a => a.GetType == StartingQuest);
    a.OgresKilled += 1;
}
```

Can someone please explain what my mistake is? And is this an efficient way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are multiple StartingQuest instances in the list? (LINQ is the way forward here, but we need a bit more detail first.)

Comment: Your error is because you have to get the type of StratingQuest: `a.GetType() == typeof(StartingQuest)`

Comment: Thanks @Magnetron, this solved the issue! It also seems I don't really understand what the right side of the == is evaluated to if I don't use typeof()

Comment: @JonSkeet that's a good point. There should never be more than one StartingQuest in the list, and the one I have even has its own name StartingQuest1, but I couldn't figure out how to seach the list for that.

Comment: You use `a.GetType == StartingQuest` which would not compile if it was the `Object.GetType` method so it seems you have hidden that method with a new property. What does it return?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I suspect there's no property involved - it's just that the use of the type name on the RHS of `==` is obscuring the error of using a method group on the LHS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers have explained aspects that are incorrect in the code in the question:

- It checks for equality between an existing quest and a brand-new `StartingQuest` instance, which is unlikely to ever be true
- It tries to use the method group `GetType` directly, instead of *calling* the method (as `a.GetType()`)
- It tries use a type name directly in the `==` expression, where you intended to evaluate a `Type` reference - `typeof` will help there.

I would suggest a slight modification of SomeBody's answer (in fact explaining an option already present in a comment).

Currently both the question and all the answers here are checking for the *exact* type `StartingQuest`, which is somewhat brittle. It's usually more useful to check whether something is a target type *or a derived type*, even if you don't currently have any derived types.

LINQ provides the `OfType` method which will find elements of a sequence in precisely that manner - and the resulting sequence has an element type of that "target type", which means that if you need to access something that's in `StartingQuest` but not the base type (`Quest` or whatever it is), you'll be fine.

So I'd definitely use:

```cs
// Import the System.Linq namespace to make the OfType and FirstOrDefault 
// extension methods available
using System.Linq;

...

var startingQuest = Globals.ActiveQuests.OfType<StartingQuest>().FirstOrDefault();
if (startingQuest is object)
{
   startingQuest.OgresKilled++;
}
```

The use of `is object` instead of `!= null` is just to use the more modern idiom for checking whether something is non-null.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` check will always fail, because you look for a new instance of `StartingQuest`. If it is a reference type, this will never be true, because the newly created instance will have a different reference than all the quests in the list. Moreover, you are iterating the list twice, one time in the `Contains` method, and one time in the `Find` method. This will fix these issues:

```
var startingQuest = Globals.ActiveQuests.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(StartingQuest));
// as an alternative, this is also possible:
// var startingQuest = Globals.ActiveQuests.OfType<StartingQuest>().FirstOrDefault();
if(!(startingQuest is null))
{
     startingQuest.OgresKilled += 1;
}
```

`FirstOrDefault` returns the first instance that matches a criterion. If no item is found, the default value of that type is returned (`null` for reference types). Hence you check whether the return value is not null. If it's not null, an item was found and you can increment your `OrgresKilled` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because you have to get the type of StartingQuest:

```
a.GetType() == typeof(StartingQuest)
```

`GetType` returns a [Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-5.0), so you also need an instance of the type `Type` to compare to. That's what `typeof` does, it returns an instance of `Type` that corresponds to the type of its argument.

Comment: While this is correct as far as it goes, I don't think it's the best way of proceeding. (I'm adding an answer now...)